# Node.js read file from shortcut (or alias or reference) path (or folder or directory)

Tags: node.js, path, alias, shortcut

```
//C:\workspace\nodeapp1\server.js
const appProps = PropertiesReader('config/myapp.properties')
global.envProps = PropertiesReader(appProps.get('env.cfgfile'))
```

`myapp.properties` inside application source contains only one static property `env.cfgfile=env_config/env.properties`

`env.properties` can be anywhere on the machine(or shared drive) contains all those tons of environment specific properties for the application.

Now, the concern is the path `env_config`, which is an alias. How to pass the actual path for this alias at runtime?

Consider the situations I deploy this on PC, Mac, VM, Docker

I believe it is applicable to any programming language like Java, Python, Node.js, PHP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out this kind of simple replacement method in any programming language will help

```
const envObj = process.env //Every language has a way to read env variables
global.getActVal = function(value) {
    for (var key in envObj) value = value.replace(key, envObj[key])
    return value
}
const appProps = PropertiesReader('config/myapp.properties')
global.envProps = PropertiesReader(getActVal(appProps.get('env.cfgfile')))
```

Every OS has a way to set the environment variables which are key-value pairs and the value here could be a directory path.

E.g. in Windows, `set env_config=C:\appconfigs\nodeapp1`